# Custom Docstrings in Python

Tags: python, docstring

How would create a custom docstring in python? Would you just say `__nameofdocstring__` or is there something else you should do?

Is it possible to create a new docstring for a certain `.py` file? I want to write `__notes__ = "blah blah blah"`, but just saying that statement won't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom docstring"? It sounds like you have something specific in mind, but you haven't made it clear what it is.

Comment: do you want to modify an existing third-party function, or is this for a function that you wrote?

Comment: FWIW, your edit didn't clarify anything

Comment: Do you want reusable components for docstrings?

Comment: @PaulH Can you explain what you think my question is currently?

Comment: @PaulH How would you make a new docstring that is not built into the python standard library?

Comment: I have no clue. It doesn't make sense to me yet. I don't know what you're starting with and your destination is even less clear

Comment: do you want this new docstring to persist in the stdlib every time your start python?

Comment: @PaulH Yes, but no. I just want a new docstring in my current python file.

Comment: i thought I was starting to understand what you wanted, but that last comment lost me. Explain what you have, what you want, and how you expect it to be used

Comment: (and by "explain", I mean: edit the question to explicitly state that information with examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Docstring Example

Let's show how an example of a multi-line docstring:

```
def my_function():
"""Do nothing, but document it.

No, really, it doesn't do anything.
"""
pass
```

Let's see how this would look like when we print it

```
print my_function.__doc__

Do nothing, but document it.

    No, really, it doesn't do anything.
```

## Declaration of docstrings

The following Python file shows the declaration of docstrings within a python
source file:

```
"""
Assuming this is file mymodule.py, then this string, being the
first statement in the file, will become the "mymodule" module's
docstring when the file is imported.
"""

class MyClass(object):
    """The class's docstring"""

    def my_method(self):
        """The method's docstring"""

def my_function():
    """The function's docstring"""
```

## How to access the Docstring

The following is an interactive session showing how the docstrings may be accessed

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> help(mymodule)
```

Assuming this is file mymodule.py then this string, being the first statement in 
the file will become the mymodule modules docstring when the file is imported.

```
>>> help(mymodule.MyClass)
The class's docstring

>>> help(mymodule.MyClass.my_method)
The method's docstring

>>> help(mymodule.my_function)
The function's docstring
```

Comment: Is that really a proper usage of a function?

Comment: "Docstring", named for "documentation". That's all. You can document what your functions are doing.

Comment: If you're problem is solved please consider marking an answer as correct (whether it be mine, your own or someone else's) so future helper gremlins like yours truly can safely skip the question. Thanks!